# How can i create a staff directory (SharePoint Online)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been doing some research and thinking of the best approach and some limitations.I came across an approach in which syncing the user profile and azure AD which then syncs to some sql azure(This approach seems ok but not sure why this much overhead).

Can't i just use SharePoint Online user profiles to get all employee records?
I want something simple that just does the job.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can take the advantage of OOTB User profile and available web parts.
There are a couple of ways to get it done.

1. you can simply use an out of the box Web Part called Contacts to manage contact information. The beauty of this approach is that you can customize your Contacts Web Part with any columns/metadata that you wish. That means you can add all sorts of phone numbers, notes, other information and group/organize it in any way you wish on your SharePoint site or page.
2. create custom sites/pages using Content Search Web part. This option works well when you have a larger organization and want to create an Employee Directory that allows you to filter the different properties using left-hand-side metadata criteria. You do need to be an advanced SharePoint User to create this sort of Directory.
3. Office 365 has a built-in User Profile Page, part of the whole Office 365 Delve experience. You can access that page by clicking on any username from within your SharePoint Online Sites.

Read this blog for complete detail about all options: http://sharepointmaven.com/create-sharepoint-employee-directory/

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your response. Would i be able to work with SharePoint userprofile directly to get all users details for the staff directory?

Answer (score 0):

Update: have a look at https://blog.hyperfish.com/employee-directory-in-office-365-and-sharepoint- ,it seems like the closest to an out of the box solution available today